# How to replace Kafka with Aeron

Tags: apache-kafka, aeron

At present, the trading system of our production environment is using Kafka. Because Kafka latency is too high, we hope to replace Kafka with Aeron. How can I use Aeron correctly?

Comment: Latency is too high? Please show your configs, certainly something is wrong... I assume you use Netflix or Uber? They use Kafka on a global scale. Go watch their conference talks. Also, Kafka is TCP, not UDP/IPC like Aeron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aeron isn't an out of the box replacement for Kafka although it does provide primitives that would allow you to replicate much of the functionality.

Kafka latencies are in the [order of milliseconds](https://www.confluent.io/blog/configure-kafka-to-minimize-latency/) whereas Aeron latencies are typically measured [in microseconds](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/low-latency-cloud-oss/).

What exactly you would need to build in Aeron very much depends on your use case.

One of the primary uses of Kafka is as a persistent queue.

To build a simple persistent queue for a single publisher use case. You would need:

**Publisher**

- `ArchivingMediaDriver` - this component runs and Aeron `MediaDriver` which handles send/receiving messages over the network and and `Archive` which allows you to record and replay streams.
- A `Publication` to send messages to be recorded by the Archive. See `AeronArchive.addRecordedPublication`.

**Subsciber(s)**

- `MediaDriver` - this component handles send/receiving messages over the network.
- A `Susbcription` that replays data from a specific position in the recorded stream of messages. See `AeronArchive.replay`.

There are examples of this in the aeron-samples.

- [RecordedBasicPublisher.java](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/master/aeron-samples/src/main/java/io/aeron/samples/archive/RecordedBasicPublisher.java)
- [ReplayedBasicSubscriber.java](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/master/aeron-samples/src/main/java/io/aeron/samples/archive/ReplayedBasicSubscriber.java)

Latency could be reduced further by having the publisher send messages over multicast/MDC and having the subscriber use `ReplayMerge` to seamlessly transition from the recorded stream to the live stream.

Worth noting that real-logic do provide commercial support.

Comment: Thanks @james for the answer, great。
Because I use a `stream` to store all Kafka topic data, how to get the topic of each record without deserialization?
thx

Comment: The trick here is to store the topic at a well known byte offset in your message. Then you can read it out without deserialising the rest of your message.

Answer (score 1):

AERON VS KAFKA
To the OP , Aeron is not Kafka although there could be significant overlap in what is doable with both. ( though with different degrees of ease). The most important difference is that Aeron ecosystem is not totally agnostic to what the application itself has to do . Kafka to a large extent is .

To get a hand of it and appreciate the differences and evaluate suitability for whatever you are trying to do , it will benefit you to use the SBE tool to generate helper classes/code for the generation and reception of your messages . For that you will need to define your messages in SBE format first. That also makes it possible to do what James is suggesting.
BTW , SBE oriented messaging underlying Aeron is one of the key reasons it is able to do its message communication with such a high throughput and low latency. The other is ofcourse further optimization of the Media Driver using DPDK and the like  to get further juice ( for that you will need Aeron Premium).

Some helpful pointers in this regard:
**SBE Page from Aeron Cookbook:** https://aeroncookbook.com/simple-binary-encoding/overview/

**SBE Tool code at Github:** https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding

**GREAT EXAMPLE TO GO THROUGH TO UNDERSTAND HOW IT ALL WORKS AND CAN WORK FOR YOU**
Go through the example provided here at AdaptiveConsulting GitHub in detail for an in depth understanding of SBE and overall how clustering and application service design works in an Aeron oriented Ecosystem:

https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/aeron-io-samples/tree/main

1. Run the example and play around with it to get an understanding of the auction "business logic" it implemented through Aeron
2. See https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/aeron-io-samples/blob/main/cluster-protocol/src/main/resources/protocol/protocol-codecs.xml , for definitions of types and messages used by the application
3. See the **SbeDeMuxer** here: **......AdaptiveConsulting/aeron-io-samples/blob/main/cluster/src/main/java/io/aeron/samples/infra/SbeDemuxer.java** to see how the incoming messages are decoded by the SBETool provided helper classes , and then depending on the type of the message , they are dispatched to the relevant message handler for processing
4. Pay attention to the clean programmatic way in which "Infra" i.e. cluster oriented stuff is isolated from the Cluster's Application Service Business Logic ( i.e. Domain ). This is here:
   **...../AdaptiveConsulting/aeron-io-samples/tree/main/cluster/src/main/java/io/aeron/samples**
5. Look at the source of the associated Admin utility to see the Cluster Client side at work .This is here: **...../AdaptiveConsulting/aeron-io-samples/tree/main/admin/src/main/java/io/aeron/samples/admin**

Specifically pay extra attention to the ClusterInteraction agent which is used to send the messages from client to Cluster. Here:
**...../AdaptiveConsulting/aeron-io-samples/blob/main/admin/src/main/java/io/aeron/samples/admin/cluster/ClusterInteractionAgent.java**

And also to complete the loop by having a look at the Egress processor i.e. the **"OnMessage"** handler of this class:
**....../AdaptiveConsulting/aeron-io-samples/blob/main/admin/src/main/java/io/aeron/samples/admin/cluster/AdminClientEgressListener.java**